# audio player for websites

Tags: media, embedding

Hi
Can anyone suggest me a good audio player for embedding in the websites?

I need a simple auio player for the website with play and pause option and with the option to download the music thats playing.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Needs a good Mp3 audio player to embed in my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545507/needs-a-good-mp3-audio-player-to-embed-in-my-website)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend this one:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/